# How can I remove old (unused?) entries for the Java Console addon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, java

Currently there are three entries in my Firefox addons list for the Java Console, v6.0.20, v6.0.19, and v6.0.16. The entries for the last two older, superseded entries are greyed out.

In particular, the only button which works is Enable/Disable. The Uninstall button can not be used.

How can I get rid of these out of date Java Console addons? I have disabled them but I would prefer to just get rid of them completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A console is installed with each Java update.  You can remove the old Java updates from the Add/Remove programs dialog in Windows. This will also remove the Java console extension in Firefox.

Java updates used to leave older updates installed, but starting with version 6.0.10 it now removes the previous update - or at least it is supposed to; it seems to have failed for you. You can safely remove all but the latest version. This [article](http://voices.washingtonpost.com/securityfix/2008/10/java_update_promises_to_remove.html) has some additional information about the change and possible security issues stemming from leaving the older versions in place.

Comment: The only Java entry I see in Win 7's "Programs and Features" dialog is the most recent, Java 6 Update 20. As far as I know the others have been uninstalled. This is why continuing to see them in Firefox puzzles me.

Comment: This article http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.support.firefox/browse_thread/thread/ce07ea5b1597f38a?pli=1 has a method to uninstall them. See comment by Cal Tinson. 

Look in C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\extensions. Find folders with the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th parts of the names matching the Java version. Remove the folders that match the consoles you want to remove. Leave the rest. Make a backup just in case.

I have Java 6.0.20 (internal version 1.6.0.20) installed and a folder named {CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-0020-ABCDEFFEDCBA}. The central part 0016-0000-0020 matches the Java version.

Comment: Thanks!! Deleting those cryptic folder in \Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\extensions did the trick. What bothered me about this was they just keep accumulating ... but they're gone now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all the Java console entries are part of the same addin.

Type "about:plugins" in the firefox url address bar to bring up a list of installed plugins and the filenames that provide them. In Windows they are .dll files in Linux, .so files, but only one filename for a group of addons.

I suspect that the older version names are kept for compatibility reasons.